# How to convert a nested loop to a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can i convert this code to list comprehension in python

```
max_len = []
for word in fourier_dict:
    word = fourier_dict[word]
    for occur in word:
        max_len.append(len(occur))
```

Im new to python and i have to convert this nested loop to a list comprehension which i cant figure out. A little help would be really appreciated.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. We expect you to show us what you've tried and a specific problem that you're having. "I want a program that does this, can somebody write it for me" is not an appropriate question for this site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
max_len = [len(occur) for word in fourier_dict for occur in fourier_dict[word]]
```

Should work.

Comment: This works 
thanks man i couldn't figure out the syntax for using two loops in a list comprehension

Answer (score 3):

So first off, you don't actually use the key of the `dict`, so you can simplify to:

```
max_len = []
for word in fourier_dict.values():
    for occur in word:
        max_len.append(len(occur))
```

directly iterating the values (use `.itervalues()` if it's Py2 code to avoid a temporary `list`). From there, it's a simple transform to a listcomp, the value to "append" is on the far left, while the loops are laid out left to right, from outer-most to inner-most:

```
max_len = [len(occur) for word in fourier_dict.values() for occur in word]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = [len(i) for a, b in fourier_dict.items() for i in b]
```

Comment: Your loops are backwards; you iterate `b` before `b` exists. You also never use `a`, so you may as well just use `.values()` over `.items()`.